# Bash - break the loop with a condition that is read from a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am using bash to run some commands until they meet the target I set.

Here is my code with explanation:

```
#!/bin/bash

#keep running some commands until a target is met
while : 
do
  #some executions that generate a number and write into flag.txt 

  #read the number from flag.txt and store in variable flag
  while read flag
  do
    echo $flag
  done <<< $(cat flag.txt)

  echo "hello $flag"

  #if the number from the file is >= the target I set (i.e. 0.717), then break the loop and finish the computation, otherwize, keep running.
  if [ $(echo "$flag >= 0.717" | bc) -eq 1 ]
  then
    break
  fi

done
```

I got some errors:

```
0.7172
hello 
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
./test.sh: line 14: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

I think this is because the 2nd while loop runs in a subshell, the value of the $flag is kept within the 2nd while loop.

```
  do
    echo $flag
  done <<< $(cat flag.txt)

  echo "hello $flag"
```

To prove this, if I change the value of $flag to a real number:

```
if [ $(echo "0.72 >= 0.717" | bc) -eq 1 ]
```

Then I can get the correct results: Apparently, the value of $flag outside the 2nd while loop is just "blank":

```
0.7172
hello
```

I wonder if there is any way to work around this?

Comment: the `read flag` that fails (causing the while loop to terminate) sets `flag` to the empty string.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do that? Thanks. @WilliamPursell

Comment: Not recommending the use of bc, but you could simply do `while read flag && test $(echo "$flag < 0.717" | bc) -eq 1 ; do echo "$flag"; done < input`

Comment: I think in your code, I still can't pass the value of $flag to the if statement, right? I need this to break from the infinite while loop.@WilliamPursell

Comment: By moving the test into the cmd checked by the while, you don't need an if statement at all.

Comment: But you've got an XY problem.  Your code doesn't really make much sense to me.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm not really sure I answered the question, but I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: This code is incomplete and confusing. Please make a [mcve] and use indentation for readability.

Comment: `... done < flag.txt`, not `... done <<< $(cat flag.txt)`.

Comment: I have edited the question, thank you so much for the feedback on editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you just need to replace:

```
  while read flag
  do
    echo $flag
  done <<< $(cat flag.txt)
  echo "hello $flag"
  if [ $(echo "$flag >= 0.717" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then
    break
  fi
```

With:

```
read flag < flag.txt
echo "hello $flag"
if test "$(echo "$flag >= 0.717" | bc)" -eq 1; then
    break
fi
```

Using the while loop to read every line in the file ends up leaving `flag` set to the empty string, because the loop doesn't terminate until `read` gets to the end of the file and sets `flag` to the empty string.  Note that, assuming the `echo "hello $flag"` is purely for debugging, you could simply do:

```
if awk '{ exit ! ($1 >= .717)}' flag.txt; then break; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should put your if statement within the nested loop. So that it can break when "target" is met. You can set another flag when this condition is met and use that flag to break out from outer loop.

The unary operator error is due to $flag not having any value and if statement evaluates only the 2nd operand.

Comment: I think the problem is what happens in the nested loop cannot be pass to the outer loop. So I cannot use 2nd flag, am I right?